# Use Custom Image Instead of Default Facebook Share button?

Tags: facebook, button, share

I'm trying to use a custom "share on facebook" image I made in photoshop instead of the default facebook share button. The idea is that when someone clicks the image the share box will be brought up. I have looked around, but can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIButton & set it's background image as "yourCustomImage" ?
If you see a problem then try to see how to add a button type custom in stack overflow.